# How to compare variables to undefined, if I don’t know whether they exist?

Tags: javascript, undefined

In JavaScript you can declare a variable and if it’s `undefined`, you can check `variable == undefined`; I know that, but how can you compare a value that you don’t know yet if it’s in memory?

For example, I have a class which is created when the user clicks a button. Before this, the class is undefined — it doesn’t exist anywhere; how can I compare it?

Is there a way without using `try`–`catch`?

Answer (score 219, accepted):

The best way is to check the **type**, because `undefined`/`null`/`false` are a tricky thing in JS.
So:

```
if(typeof obj !== "undefined") {
    // obj is a valid variable, do something here.
}
```

Note that `typeof` always returns a string, and doesn't generate an error if the variable doesn't exist at all.

Comment: make that `if(typeof obj !== "undefined") {}` and it's perfect (notice second equals sign)

Comment: What is the trick stuff? Why not only doring a direct comparison like Timmys answer?

Comment: You can just use `obj !== undefined` now. `undefined` used to be mutable, like `undefined = 1234` what would cause interesting results. But after Ecmascript 5, it's not writable anymore, so we can use the simpler version. http://www.codereadability.com/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript/

Comment: Beware that `obj` may be `null` or `false`, in which case my guess is that you wouldn't want to execute such code either. Of course there can be exceptions and special cases. `null`, `false`, `undefined` are all "falsy" values and they can be easily evaluated like this: `if (obj) { ... }`

Comment: @AmyPellegrini my example above will still work, because typeof will not fire an error even if the variable is null or false. That's the beauty of it.

Comment: @MakramSaleh it will not fire an error, but it will pass evaluation as "true" if `obj === null` or `obj === false`. Just a warning, of course the context and the content inside `if` will determine if the code fails or not.

Comment: @Raveren you don't need a type enforcing comparison, both side are already strings and type inference won't happen

Comment: let options = null
undefined
> typeof options
'object'
if the value is null we have a problem

Comment: If using `typeof` like this it is best use `typeof` on both sides, e.g. `if (typeof obj !== typeof undefined)`. Both from a nice symmetry point of view, but also to guard against inadvertently comparing against "undefnied" etc.

Comment: @hlovdal thats smart, that small typeo could cause major headaches.  I'm guessing typeof is an O(1) hash table lookup though?  also, is there a difference between using `typeof undefined` and just `undefined` other than the O(1) overhead?

Answer (score 81):

```
if (obj === undefined)
{
    // Create obj
}
```

If you are doing extensive javascript programming you should get in the habit of using `===` and `!==` when you want to make a type specific check.

Also if you are going to be doing a fair amount of javascript, I suggest running code through JSLint http://www.jslint.com it might seem a bit draconian at first, but most of the things JSLint warns you about will eventually come back to bite you.

Comment: What is one situation where a thing which is not `undefined` would `== undefined`?

Comment: @JesseDhillon - "null == undefined" is true.  "null === undefined" is not.

Comment: Please use `typeof var === 'undefined'` as `undefined` is not a constant in JavaScript

Comment: Doesn't work, Makram's `typeof` solution works.

Comment: Needs to use typeof.

Comment: Since ECMA Script 5 (2009), 'undefined' is a constant and use of typeof is NOT required. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? https://imgur.com/a/UyWDKd8

Comment: @SamyBencherif Despite the confusing naming, `undefined` is not the same as trying to reference a variable that has not been defined.

Comment: I'd recommend `obj === void 0`.  It is ES1, is less to type, is more readable (YMMV) and works even with `undefined = 'Wubba Lubba Dub Dub!'`.

Comment: I recommend using "obj === void null" for reasons of readability.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (document.getElementById('theElement')) // do whatever after this
```

For undefined things that throw errors, test the property name of the parent object instead of just the variable name - so instead of:

```
if (blah) ...
```

do:

```
if (window.blah) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`!undefined` is true in javascript, so if you want to know whether your variable or object is undefined and want to take actions, you could do something like this:

```
if(<object or variable>) {
     //take actions if object is not undefined
} else {
     //take actions if object is undefined
}
```

Comment: thanks for you time but, I this case if you try to compare an undeclared variable you are going get a error throw saying you haven't declare the variable... so is impossible to compare it... so is why you need to transform the type of the variable in a string format in a way to compare it successfully 

example
if( type of myundeclaredvarible == "undefined") //do something best nahum @Rahul Panday

Comment: you already edited the last one is quite cool never seen before thanks :)

Answer (score -3):

```
if (!obj) {
    // object (not class!) doesn't exist yet
}
else ...
```

Comment: obj may very well exist but be false or 0.

Comment: Regular object cannot be just `false` or `0`. It should contain pairs of `key -> value`, or empty, or undefined, or null.

Comment: That was not the question though. Just because you call a variable obj it may still be anything imho.

Comment: `'I have a class which is created when the user clicks a button. Before this the class is undefined, it doesn't exist anywhere so how can I compare it?` - that was a question.

Comment: -1. Question includes `you can check variable == undefined`.  `!obj` is even is worse than `obj == undefined`.  Compare `!NaN` (true) vs. `NaN == undefined` (false)