# How to check 'undefined' value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting an undefined object property in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript)
>   [javascript undefined compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778901/javascript-undefined-compare)

How we can add a check for an undefined variable, like:

```
function A(val) {
  if (val == undefined) 
    // do this
  else
    // do this
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Answer (score 446, accepted):

JQuery library was developed specifically to simplify and to unify certain JavaScript functionality.

However if you need to check a variable against `undefined` value, there is no need to invent any special method, since JavaScript has a [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator, which is simple, fast and cross-platform:

```
if (typeof value === "undefined") {
    // ...
}
```

It returns a string indicating the type of the variable or other unevaluated operand. The main advantage of this method, compared to `if (value === undefined) { ... }`, is that `typeof` will never raise an exception in case if variable `value` does not exist.

Comment: @nahum jQuery is a JavaScript library. [***This is not a different programming language.***](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48195/187073)

Comment: lol omg are you really commenting this?? I know is the same man. But I guess he want to know if exist some kind of method in jQuery like $.isUndefined(Object); and return the value true or false. typeof is just javascript without any framework.

Comment: One of my problems was:

if you are doing something like this `("#myId")`, make sure what do you really need:

a. `typeof ("#myId")=== "undefined"`


b. Or: `typeof ("#myId").val() === "undefined"`

Comment: @Alberici `("#myId")` is nothing else but a **string** constant. It will always be defined and have a type of `"string"`. If you mean an actual *jQuery object* created with `$("#myId")`, it will always be defined as `"object"` (if you have jQuery linked correctly). Existence of a DOM element with ID `myId` can be assessed with `if ($("#myId").length > 0) { ... }`, while check if its value is not empty can be done with `if ($("#myId").val()) { ... }`. Neither of these clauses actually relate to the topic of this question.

Comment: From jquery 1.4.2, you can use `$.type(selector) === 'undefined'` to check `undefined` value. Source: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/

Comment: it's supposed to be `value === undefined` **without** quotes. @Hast This works in jQuery

Comment: @user3284463 As mentioned in the answer, simple `value === undefined` will raise an exception if `value` variable does not exist. So it's completely up to you what to use in the real life.

Answer (score 32):

In this case you can use a `=== undefined` comparison: `if(val === undefined)`

This works because `val` always *exists* (it's a function argument).

If you wanted to test an arbitrary variable that is not an argument, i.e. might not be defined at all, you'd have to use `if(typeof val === 'undefined')` to avoid an exception in case `val` didn't exist.

Answer (score 17):

Note that typeof always returns a string, and doesn't generate an error if the variable doesn't exist at all.

```
function A(val){
  if(typeof(val)  === "undefined") 
    //do this
  else
   //do this
}
```

Comment: For string comparison, I think we need to use `===` instead of `==`

Comment: @Sreeram they both do comparison, just in different ways...this will work fine

Answer (score 12):

I know I am late to answer the function but jquery have a in build function to do this

```
if(jQuery.type(val) === "undefined"){
    //Some code goes here
}
```

Refer jquery API document of jquery.type https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/ for the same.

Answer (score 5):

You can use shorthand technique to check whether it is undefined or null

```
 function A(val)
 {
   if(val || "") 
   //do this
 else
 //do this
 }
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

when I am testing "`typeof obj === undefined`", the `alert(typeof obj)` returning `object`, even though obj is undefined.
Since obj is type of `Object` its returning `Object`, not `undefined`.

So after hours of testing I opted below technique.

```
if(document.getElementById(obj) !== null){
//do...
}else{
//do...
}
```

I am not sure why the first technique didn't work.But I get done my work using this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have names of the element and not id we can achieve the undefined check on all text elements (for example) as below and fill them with a default value say 0.0:

```
var aFieldsCannotBeNull=['ast_chkacc_bwr','ast_savacc_bwr'];
 jQuery.each(aFieldsCannotBeNull,function(nShowIndex,sShowKey) {
   var $_oField = jQuery("input[name='"+sShowKey+"']");
   if($_oField.val().trim().length === 0){
       $_oField.val('0.0')
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is the best solution, but it works fine:

```
if($someObject['length']!=0){
    //do someting
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isValue(value, def, is_return) {
    if ( $.type(value) == 'null'
        || $.type(value) == 'undefined'
        || $.trim(value) == ''
        || ($.type(value) == 'number' && !$.isNumeric(value))
        || ($.type(value) == 'array' && value.length == 0)
        || ($.type(value) == 'object' && $.isEmptyObject(value)) ) {
        return ($.type(def) != 'undefined') ? def : false;
    } else {
        return ($.type(is_return) == 'boolean' && is_return === true ? value : true);
    }
}
```

try this~ all type checker

Answer (score 0):

Check if undefined or not

```
if(typeof myVal === "undefined") {
   //some code
}
```

Check if undefined or null or empty or false or 0

```
if(!myVal) {
   // some code
} else {
   // myVal is flawless 
}
```

Comment: What new this answer bring other than already said in other answers?

Answer (score 0):

Try code about check ur code jQuery:

```
if (window.jQuery) { 
  console.log("Actived: jQuery");
} else {
  console.log("Disabled: jQuery");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Example variable
var myVariable;

// Using standard JavaScript methods
if (typeof myVariable === 'undefined') {
    console.log('myVariable is undefined');
}

// Using jQuery's utility function
if ($.type(myVariable) === 'undefined') {
    console.log('myVariable is undefined');
}
```