# Check which variable is undefined in a JS Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to understand how to check which variable(s) are not defined in an array and how to do something with them. Unfortunately the code I have would overwrite variables which have already been set in the script.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {      

    if(window['user' + i] == undefined){

       window['user' + i] = // DO SOMETHING WITH THE VARIABLE WHICH IS NOT DEFINED

    }
}
```

Comment: use `typeof(variable) == "undefined"`

Comment: need a better explanation of issue and why you are using `window['user' + i]`. What is objective?

Comment: @Ravi  what's wrong with his way?

Comment: @Ravi Why wouldn't it? http://jsfiddle.net/a8wfg2pv/

Comment: Try this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778901/javascript-undefined-compare

Comment: _your script works_ @Karl-Andre-Gagnon tested it and I have tested it locally and I can't get it **not** to work.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon The `typeof` operator is guaranteed to return a string. Direct comparisons against `undefined` are troublesome as undefined can be overwritten.  `window.undefined = "omg"; 
"omg" == undefined // true`. But is ES5, maybe is worth mentioning that undefined is now described as non-writable, non-configurable and non-enumerable. So this will not be the case in modern browsers.

Comment: @Ravi my code can check if a variable is set or not. My problem is that i don't know which variable is undefined since it's in an array.

Comment: @Ravi I'm not saying typeof is bad, I do recommend it. But his code is fine. And you need to be really stupid to override the `window.undefined`.... `== undefined` is *good enough* when you test an object property, argument or array index. Testing a variable though will throw an error.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I am not saying it cannot do that, but it's just conventional and effective to check by type for undefined values. That's all.

Comment: @Ravi I wouldn't say conventional, since a lot of plugin use `=== undefined` for a slightly better performance. They initiate their plugin like that : `(function($, undefined){}).call(window, jQuery)`. But yeah, outside a closure like that, `typeof` is foolproof!

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon ("since a lot of plugin use" == "conventional") to me :) . And yeah, `===` is more appropriate for type checking.

Comment: @Ravi That's what I meant ;) `=== undefined` is not in quote so, i was saying `x === undefined` (no `typeof()`). Anyway, now this discussion is diverging from the OP and I think we understood each other! So, have a good day sir!

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Not a sir, i'm just a beginner, trying hard to make sense to others. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are two types of undefined properties**: those which have not been defined, and those which have been set to `undefined`.

**If you need to detect properties which have not been defined on on object (or array), use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`**, like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {      
    if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(window, 'user' + i)) {
        window['user' + i] = // DO SOMETHING WITH THE VARIABLE WHICH IS NOT DEFINED
    }
}
```

Since `window` is an Object, you can also call `hasOwnProperty` directly through it, *if* you trust that nobody has set it (or `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`, which `window` inherits) to something else. The code for that would look like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {      
    if (!window.hasOwnProperty('user' + i)) {
        window['user' + i] = // DO SOMETHING WITH THE VARIABLE WHICH IS NOT DEFINED
    }
}
```

**If you need to specifically detect properties set to `undefined`, then start with the previous check and if true, check the value**. Assuming that no one has changed `window.hasOwnProperty`, that would look like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {      
    if (window.hasOwnProperty('user' + i) && window['user' + i] === undefined) {
        window['user' + i] = // DO SOMETHING WITH THE VARIABLE WHICH IS NOT DEFINED
    }
}
```

**You may also need to check for properties that are undefined, or set to `undefined` or `null`**. Again assuming that no one has changed `window.hasOwnProperty`, that might look like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {      
    if (!window.hasOwnProperty('user' + i) || window['user' + i] === undefined || window['user' + i] === null) {
        window['user' + i] = // DO SOMETHING WITH THE VARIABLE WHICH IS NOT DEFINED
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlexanderC If this is what you need you should mark this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe this also works if your just you're just looking for any values that could be false as well

```
    if(!window['user' + i])
```

Comment: It will catch falsy value, maybe the OP can defined the variable to `false`, `0` or any other falsy value...

Comment: What do you mean doesn't this catch undefined.  example run this in your browser console.
     `var Temp = {};
     if(!temp["test"]){console.log('this is not defined')}`

this should log "this is not defined"

Comment: I did not said it doesn't catch `undefined`, I said it catch falsy value. undefined is a falsy value, so it catch it. But 0 is also falsy. Test: `var temp = {x:0}; if(!temp["x"]){console.log('this is not defined')}`. OP wouldnt want to log to pop here.

Comment: I just realized what you meant.  I editted my response you can use this depending on the scenario.