# Check if getAttribute is not undefined

Tags: javascript

Currently, my javascript is creating pages dynamically, so when the user clicks X, the new html code is generated for that option, if B then vice versa.

Although, I'm getting "undefined" errors. Even though I do check for the variables before they're passed into the function.

My current non-working prototype looks like this

```
var appName; 
    if(evt.target.getAttribute("appName") != "" || evt.target.getAttribute("appName") != null){
        appName = evt.target.getAttribute("appName");
    }
```

Before that, I've tried using something which looks like this

```
var appName = evt.target.get("appName");
    if (typeof appName != typeof undefined && appName !== false) {
        appName = evt.target.getAttribute("appName");
    }
    else appName = 'boo';
```

That still returns undefined.

Lastly, I tried more or less the same approach but it still returns 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined`
The code for the following looks like that :

```
var appName = '';
    if(evt.target.hasAttribute("appName")){
        appName = evt.target.getAttribute("appName");
    } 
    else appName = 'boo';
```

How would I check if the attribute is actually set and I can proceed if not then I would like to pick alternate course for the code.

Thanks for your help and time spent.

Comment: Please provide HTML and the whole function, please.

Comment: The error is telling something else. `Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined` mean your `evt.target` is undefined.

Comment: As a side note: Use strict inequality `!==` instead of loose  `!=`. Also use `===` instead of `==`

Comment: With little context around event provided in the question,  if your'e aiming to check undefined you can do this:
if(event.target && event.target.getAttribute(...)) {// rest of your code} else {//alternate block}

Comment: Can you show your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`evt.target` is undefined, which means that you need to check for that before trying `getAttribute()`. This is one of the options you have, mostly depending on what your "alternate course for the code" is:

```
var appName; 
    if(evt && evt.target && ( evt.target.getAttribute("appName") != "" || evt.target.getAttribute("appName") != null )){
        appName = evt.target.getAttribute("appName");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if something is undefined by doing this (Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2779104/11564138)):

```
if(typeof obj !== "undefined") {
    // obj is a valid variable, do something here.
}
```

Note that typeof always returns a string. Also, there's a difference between comparing with "double equals" and "triple equals" so you might want to check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) out.

Answer (score 0):

I have provided the sample snippet.

> you have tried `evt.target.getAttribute` instead try `evt.getAttribute`

Try like this.

```js
function findAttr(e){
  if (!e.hasAttribute("appName")) {
    console.log("No attribute");
  } else {
    console.log(e.getAttribute("appName"));
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div onclick="findAttr(this)">is attr present?</div>
<div onclick="findAttr(this)" appName="test">is attr present?</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an alternate state for your element determined by the presence/absence of an attribute then use `.toggleAttribute()`

```js
function editMode(e) {
  const clicked = e.target;
  const editor = document.querySelector('.editor');

  if (clicked.matches('.mode')) {
    clicked.classList.toggle('on');
    clicked.classList.toggle('off');
    editor.toggleAttribute('contenteditable');
    if (clicked.matches('.off')) {
      editor.focus();
    } else {
      editor.blur();
    }
  }
  return false;
}

document.querySelector('.mode').onclick = editMode;
```

```css
.editor {
  min-height: 32px
}

.mode {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

.on::before {
  content: 'READ/WRITE';
}

.off::before {
  content: 'READ ONLY';
}
```

```html
<fieldset class='editor'></fieldset>
<button class='mode on'></button>
```