# Javascript | Loop through array of objects using against an object

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects as following:

```
const objArray = [
    {scope: "xx", sector: "yy", status: "pending", country: "USA"},
    {scope: "zz", sector: "yy", status: "pending", country: "USA"}
    {scope: "xx", sector: "yy", status: "pending", country: "USA"}
]
```

And an object as following:

```
const compare = {scope: "xx", sector: "yy"}
```

or that one:

```
const compare = {scope: "xx"}
```

or that one:

```
const compare = {scope: "yy"}
```

I want to loop through the array of objects using one of those three `compare` objects, and return all objects that match with any one of those three `compare` examples objects with same `scope` and `sector` or `scope` only or `sector` only.

I have tried `.filter()` function, but didn't get it to work:

```
const filteredCards = objArray.filter(card =>{
    return card.scope   === compare.scope
        && card.sector  === compare.sector;
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried? `.filter()` should work.

Comment: @Halcyon, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that your filter has optional fields so if a field is not defined in the filter any value will do. I think this will work:

```
const filteredCards = objArray.filter(card =>{
    return (typeof compare.scope === "undefined" || card.scope === compare.scope)
        && (typeof compare.sector === "undefined" || card.sector === compare.sector)
        && (typeof compare.status === "undefined" || card.status === compare.status)
        && (typeof compare.country === "undefined" || card.country === compare.country);
});
```

Either the filter does not specify a value for the field, or the value matches. Repeat for each field.

Comment: That's what I thought too. You can write in a shorter way using `in` operator like `!'scope' in compare || ...`

Comment: @marekful oh that's fancy. I'm old skool =)

Comment: Are we sure it's desirable to hardcode all of the relevant fields? Seems like the same scenario as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57421569/javascript-loop-through-array-of-objects-using-against-an-object/57421708#comment101322533_57421639)

Comment: @ggorlen it depends. If you're only ever going to have 4 fields either way is fine. Glen's if-else tree is going to grow exponentially, whereas this solution is linear. I mostly chose this verbatim way of writing the filter to explain what's going on. With something as esoteric as `(([k, v]) => e[k] === v)` I have to read it twice to make sure it's doing what I think it's doing. And you have to check you're _eaching_ over the filter and not the data etc. It's not as nice to read I think. Also my linting tool would give you a big fat _no_ .. so xD

Comment: Sure, that's valid, but complexity aside, the function needs to be rewritten any time the object changes, and we're stuck with a big conditional which linters also correctly complain about. My preference in that case would be to write it "vanilla"-style but still not use literals as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57421663/6243352). I'm not really married to modern JS, but I also don't mind it either.

Answer (score 4):

Please try this code.

```js
const compare = {scope: "xx"};

const objArray = [
    {scope: "xx", sector: "yy", status: "pending", country: "USA"},
    {scope: "zz", sector: "yy", status: "pending", country: "USA"},
    {scope: "xx", sector: "yy", status: "pending", country: "USA"}
];


var filter_result = objArray.filter(function(item) {
  for (var key in compare) {
    if (item[key] === undefined || item[key] != compare[key])
      return false;
  }
  return true;
});

console.log(filter_result)
```

Answer (score 3):

Filter is the way to go, but we may as well make the test dynamic instead of hardcoding the fields in question. Let's write a function that accepts the data array and filters by a query object, returning only items in the array that have a matching value for every property in the query object:

```js
const filterByQuery = (data, query) => 
  data.filter(e => Object.entries(query).every(([k, v]) => e[k] === v))
;

const data = [
  {scope: "xx", sector: "yy", status: "pending", country: "USA"},
  {scope: "zz", sector: "yy", status: "pending", country: "USA"},
  {scope: "xx", sector: "yy", status: "pending", country: "USA"}
];

[
  {scope: "xx", sector: "yy"},
  {scope: "xx"},
  {scope: "yy"},
].forEach(query => console.log(filterByQuery(data, query)));
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can fit it one line if you tried ;)

Comment: Maybe on your monitor!

Comment: "Maybe on your monitor!" rofl. One-liners are nice in some single-use-cases, however, here on SO readability is preferable.

Comment: Your vibe is wrong. I think one-liners are less readable to the public. Furthermore they are less reusable.

Comment: @ggorlen actually that answer is problematic in 1995 because of the direct comparison with `undefined`. Apparently it's allowed now, I did not know that before today https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778901/how-to-compare-variables-to-undefined-if-i-don-t-know-whether-they-exist

Comment: To further improve the comparision method, one could implement a feature switch and use `Object.is` instead of `===` if available (or use the polyfill). https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is

Comment: I'm not sure if my English is as bad as you do not understand what I am trying to say. I don't see any one-liner in your code. It is wellformed and splitted into a separate callback and a looped invocation. It is readable formatted IN OPPOSITE to a one-liner. Actually this answer did get my unique UV.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. Thanks for clarifying.